# Outer measure of empty set is $0$ .

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

By definition of outer measure, we have $$m^*(A) = \inf\{m^*(G)\mid A\subset G, G \,\text{open in} \,[0,1]\}$$
Then my proof is as follow. Since $\emptyset\subset(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, by definition of $m^*(\emptyset)$ is infimum (lower bound) , we have $m^*(\emptyset)\leq 2\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $m^*(\emptyset)=0$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: sorry, I have editted it.

Comment: $\emptyset$ itself is open. So it is not completely rigorous to use this definition to find out its outer measure. We may use another definition of outer measure, which involves intervals and their lengths.

Comment: isn't this definition holds for any kind of subset?

Comment: Yes, but it is sort of circular for open sets. Since you are taking infimum over all open sets containing the empty set, which includes the open set. So you won't know the infimum prior to knowing $m^*(\emptyset)$.

Comment: So instead, I just say , $\emptyset$ is actually $(a,a)$ then conclude that $m^*(\emptyset) = m^*((a,a)) = 0$ by definition of outer measure for interval?

Comment: Some books require intervals to be non-empty. Your proof is basically correct, you only need to use an alternative definition and to show that $m^*(\emptyset) \geq 0$.

Comment: There is nothing circular in the definition. You first define $m^*$ on intervals. Then you extend it to all subsets using the definition OP gave in the question. You can prove that this (new) definition of $m^*$ coincides with the original definition of $m^*$ on open sets.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the proof that the singleton set $\{0\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, since it is also contained in all of your intervals $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, your correct argument applies (thought there are some details that could be filled in).

Remember that the empty set is a subset of every set, so as soon as you have a sequence of sets whose outer measure goes to $0$, you could use the same argument to show that $m^*(\emptyset)=0$, although I think this is sometimes taken as an axiom, or a part or defining the length of an open interval $(a,b)$ to be $b-a$, since $\emptyset$ could be thought of as $(a,a)$.

Also, once you know that $m^*(\{0\}) = 0$, it follows that $m^*(\emptyset) = 0$, since $\emptyset \subset \{0\}$.

Comment: What details I have missed out ? Is my proof correct actually?

Comment: I guess just the definition of outer measure for open sets $G\subset [0,1]$, which I assumed you meant to be the total length of all open intervals comprising $G$, which is how the Lebesgue outer measure is defined. For example, if $m^*$ assigned some point mass to the origin, then the outer measure of $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ would not go to $0$, and your argument wouldn't work.

Comment: I guess the main point is that $\{\text{ open } G ~|~ \emptyset \subset G\} = \{ \text{ all open subsets of } [0,1]\}$